# How do you pronounce Richard Courant's surname?

Tags: terminology, math-history

Since his surname looks rather French than German, I started wondering how you pronounce his name. In particular, I'd be interested in how he would have pronounced his name himself (since I already got quite some different answers)

Comment: Ker-Awnt is how we pronounced it at the Courant Institute.

Comment: As a Wikipedia look-up says that he was born to a German, I would suggest figuring out whether Courant as a surname has any possible German roots, independent of French: if Courant is strictly a French surname (as it certainly sounds like it), then you can probably conclude that he had some French ancestry and therefore his surname would be pronounced as the French do. On the other hand, if Courant is an "authentic" German name, then perhaps the pronunciation would be more... German.

Comment: French: like in English "Coorawn(t)" (silent t) e.g. [link](http://de.forvo.com/word/richard_courant/). In Dutch perhaps "Crunt" (Krant = newspaper) :-) Sadly I found no reference how his contemporaries actually called him. A German version would sound like "Coorunt".

Answer (score 5):

My husband is one of Richard Courant's grandsons.  The family pronounces it
Koor Awnt - even accent on both syllables, like a spondee.  Closest to the pronunciation shown above from the Courant Institute.

Answer (score 0):

I have always said Richard *Koo-ron*.